# How do I get instance of Distributed Transaction Manager

Tags: scalardb

I am following this example to test ScalarDB.

https://github.com/indetail-blockchain/getting-started-with-scalardb

The example says

"
Execute a transaction
A DistributedTransaction can be retrieved from the transactionManager. Then use this objects to execute the desired operations and eventually commit them.
"

It is not clear though from the example what is `transactionManager` and how to create DistributedTransaction from it.

How do I create a DistributedTransaction instance?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the way.

https://github.com/scalar-labs/scalardb/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md#store--retrieve-data-with-transaction-service

```
Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new TransactionModule(new DatabaseConfig(props)));
TransactionService service = injector.getInstance(TransactionService.class);
DistributedTransaction tx = service.start();
```